# Odoo 12 - Generate and download CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I have added a menu item in Reporting Tab in Manufacturing module. I have already written python code to create CSV file. But unable to figure out how to make it downloadable when I click the menu item in manufacturing module.
Here is the menu item code:

```
 <record model="ir.actions.server" id="raw_material_planning">
    <field name="name">Raw Material Planning</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="res_model">gear.manufacturing</field>
    <field name="model_id">342</field>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        action = model.raw_material_planning()
    </field>
  </record>

  <menuitem name="Raw Material Planning" parent="mrp.menu_mrp_reporting" id="menu_raw_material_planning"
      action="raw_material_planning"/>
```

Also, it should directly download and not go to any window.

**UPDATE**

saved dictionary to CSV file

```
files = base64.b64encode(open('test.csv','rb').read())

attachment = self.env['ir.attachment'].create({
            'name': 'test.csv',
            'datas': files,
            'datas_fname': 'test.csv'
        })

return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': '/web/content/%s?download=true' % (attachment.id),
            # 'target': 'new',
            'nodestroy': False,
        }
```

Kindly assist me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is all controllers are available for download contents or files.

You need to return any of controller with your file content it will automatically download.

```
[
  '/web/content',
  '/web/content/<string:xmlid>',
  '/web/content/<string:xmlid>/<string:filename>',
  '/web/content/<int:id>',
  '/web/content/<int:id>/<string:filename>',
  '/web/content/<int:id>-<string:unique>',
  '/web/content/<int:id>-<string:unique>/<string:filename>',
  '/web/content/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>',
  '/web/content/<string:model>/<int:id>/<string:field>/<string:filename>'
]
```

For download any file you need to create one attachment record for `ir.attachment`.

Then just add below code in your function for return file to url.

```
attachment = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([('name', '=', 'import_product_sample')])
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'url': '/web/content/%s?download=true' % (attachment.id),
    'target': 'new',
    'nodestroy': False,
}
```

It will automatically download your file in browser.

Comment: I have followed your instructions (updated question with your suggestion) but when I click the menu item, a new blank window appear in browser.

Comment: Did you checked in database your attachment record is created or not?